# Throwing a runtime exception deliberately

Tags: java, exception

I was going through the following code:

```
public int returnSomething() {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException("foo!");
    } finally {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Please explain what this piece of code is doing. My analysis is that we are throwing a runtime exception inside the method, but after that, the "finally" block will definitely execute. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried it, and which bit is still confusing to you?

Comment: @JonSkeet return 0 one is confusing..

Comment: So did you try it? And did you then research why you got the results you did?

Comment: @user2094103, but what is the use of this type of method? may we know the use case of this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the [Java Language Specification section 14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2). You need to be aware that returning counts as "completing abruptly":

> ...
>
> - If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, then there is a choice
>
>   - [...]
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for any reason, then the try statement completes abruptly for the same reason.

(All paths have that same final point, with some slightly different wording.)

So the overall result is that 0 is returned and the exception is discarded.

It's rarely a good idea to return from a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the finally block always gets executed. The only few reasons I know it won't execute is when you pull the plug or your JVM crashes. SO I reckon this will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

A quick test shows that this returns 0, instead of propagating the RuntimeException.

```
public class Test {
  public static int returnSomething() {
    try {
      throw new RuntimeException("foo!");
    } finally {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=returnSomething();
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```